# How to config java.util.Properties as JNDI in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jndi

How to configure a properties file content into Tomcat to recover by JNDI? like a DataSource but in this case it's a `Properties`.

In **Jetty server** I can configure this way:

```
 <New id="props-users" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
  <Arg>props/users</Arg>
  <Arg>
   <New class="java.util.Properties">
    <Put name="url">http://127.0.0.0:5984</Put>
    <Put name="schema">users</Put>
    <Put name="user">mary</Put>
    <Put name="password">secret</Put>
   </New>
  </Arg>
 </New>
```

In **Glassfish server** I can configure this way:

```
<custom-resource factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory" description="Properties to CouchDb enviroment" res-type="java.util.Properties" jndi-name="props/users">
   <property name="url" value="http://127.0.0.0:5984"></property>
   <property name="schema" value="users"></property>
   <property name="user" value="mary"></property>
   <property name="password" value="secret"></property>
 </custom-resource>
```

Tomcat, there are a custom or in the box implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I create an factory for to access a Properties as JNDI resource in tomcat. [Properties as JNDI](https://github.com/alisson-gomesc/jkniv-jaas/blob/master/jkniv-jaas-common/src/main/java/net/sf/jkniv/jaas/jndi/JndiPropertyFactory.java)

In `<tomcat-install>/conf/server.xml`

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

  <Resource auth="Container" description="Conexao clientes CouchDB" 
   name="props/myDS" 
   type="java.util.Properties"
   url="http://127.0.0.1:5984" 
   schema="mydatabase" 
   userName="admin" 
   password="secret123"
   factory="net.sf.jkniv.jaas.jndi.JndiPropertyFactory" />
```

in `web.xml` file

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>properties for connection<description>
  <res-ref-name>props/myDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>java.util.Properties</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
  <mapped-name>props/myDS</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```

in `context.xml` file

```
<Context path="/myapp" reloadable="true">

  <ResourceLink name="props/myDS"  global="props/myDS" type="java.util.Properties" />
```